# Rails remote links without jQuery and UJS and alternatives

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

I'm trying to optimise an application, written in Rails that depends quite a lot on "remote" links and forms (AJAX triggers). The thing is, that's pretty much all what we need jQuery for, so it seems like an overkill to use it. I was thinking is there a lighter approach to that, maybe replace/rewrite UJS to use some lighter javascript library (or none at all) and still get it working properly.

Comment: I am interested in this from the perspective of wanting to prevent sloppy ad hoc JQuery code by making JQuery unavailable to us developers.

Comment: @GabeKopley well, you could start by checking out http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ Building an AJAX handler is not so hard, and with `documentQueryAll` you'll come pretty far

Comment: Have you looked into knockout.js?

Comment: Of course there's something lighter than jQuery .. Straight JavaScript. But Rails UJS is a proper solution that uses jQuery to binds events to objects at the right time in page loading and rendering.  In general it's optimal using what we all agree is a great and common js library with well optimized (precompiled, compressed, minified js assuming you're using asset pipeline) implementation. What demonstrates to you that there is a real performance problem  you need to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since rails 3.0 ActionView helpers do not generate obtrusive inline javascript. All you need to know in order to make an ajax request is contained in the generated DOM. So feel free to create a ujs-driver for your prefered javascript library.

However, I personally would not do this. JQuery is not such a big overkill. And considering the fact that you can link it to your page from some CDN and the probability of the jquery having been previously cached in a user's browser very high, the benefits of getting rid of JQuery will be overwhelmed by the amount of time you'll spend developing/debugging/supporting your custom driver

Comment: You are right, it just seems _wrong_ to use whole library for 10% of it's functionality

Comment: @TomažZaman I think Knuth said it best... ""Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." If you're loading jQuery minified or from a CDN, you probably have more interesting problems to worry about. :)

Comment: Learn from the proper answer of @engineerDave. If you can measure a performance problem, that's a very good first step towards deciding if it is the thing that is most important to users.  They don't care what's "right" or "wrong" just what matters.  Many of us with engineering brains try to get things right, at the expense of time and effort in making them do what users actually need.  Google "premature optimization" to get a less polite view of what You should be hearing from responses so far.